# How to change Android usb connect mode to charge only?

Tags: android, usb

I've seen HTC android devices have connect mode selection when connected to PC via usb line, while mine always pops up a `USB massive storage device` dialog with a button `turn on massive storage`, which is boring, because sometimes my line could be loose, and `off/on` randomly, so the pop up always show up suddenly and intrudes my input when I'm doing something else. Is the a way to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HTC devices have the `PCSII.apk` which allow them to select usb connect mode. For your device, you can set it manually:

Use SQLite Editor to open `/data/data/com.android.providers.setting/databases/settings.db`

open table `secure`

turn settings starting with  `mount_ums_` to 0, then restart devices.

UPDATE:
If it still doesn't work, try turning on debug mode.

Comment: I just added a different solution which may or may not work depending on which of the many Androids out there you have.

Answer (score 19):

I have been searching for this for ages on my CM 11 android phone, running kitkat.

Well.. finally I found it. It's hidden in a totally unintuitive location:

1. Go to settings
2. Go to **storage**
3. Open the menu and choose **USB computer connection**

Here you can choose between Media Device (MTP), Camera (PTP) and Mass storage (UMS). Turn them all off to get it to charge only.

Sadly, if the option is not there, it is not supported by the phone. This seems to be the case for my HTC One (M7).

Comment: If you only see Media Device (MTP) and Camera (PTP), and if you absolutely have to select one or the other, does this mean that charge-only is not supported?

Comment: It would be strange, but yes, that seems to be the case. Can you supply a screenshot?

Answer (score 5):

Nothing worked until I went this way:
Settings>Developer options>Default USB configuration
now you can choose your default USB connection purpose.

Answer (score 2):

To change the connect mode selection try Settings -> Wireless & Networks -> USB Connection. You can shoose to Charging, Mass Storage, Tethered, and ask on connection.

Answer (score 1):

In your phone go to `Settings->Connect` to PC.

There you will see the option `Default Connection Type`. Select it and set it to your preference.

Comment: @JamesFu, Do you have "Connect to PC" setting? If not it might be in the "Power" option.