# Side effects of Settings.Secure.putInt

Tags: android, security, usb, settings, system

I want to disable USB access to an android device.

If the device is connected to a computer it should only charge and prevent any data transmission. So no one can access the data on this device.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698979/how-to-change-android-usb-connect-mode-to-charge-only), that I can change the usb settings by changing entries in the settings database.

I want to do this programmatically, because I want to turn usb access on and off (the button for this will be secured by a password).

My app runs as system app and has the permission to executute the following function.

```
Settings.Secure.putInt
```

After changing "mount_play_not_snd" with above function, I looked into the database using adb shell.
The entry

```
5|mount_play_not_snd|1
```

was gone.
But I found a new entry:

```
37|mount_play_not_snd|0
```

So I think the old entry was deleted and the new one was inserted at the end of the table instead of altering the existing entry.

Are there any side effects of the changed _ID?
Or is there a way to manipulate this database programmatically without changing the _IDs of its entries?

My device runs Android 4.4.4. Maybe the bahavior is different on other systems.

Comment: Post your code.  Since this is a db, you probably used insert and delete instead of update.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply.

I used this function:
    Settings.Secure.putInt(getActivity().getContentResolver(), "mount_play_not_sndt", 0);

In the api I only found get and put functions.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html